# How to save custom messages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a simple plugin that check if **action** (GET) paramenter is set, if there is this paramenter the plugin does few operations.

Now, I'm looking for a method to save the result of this operation. The result is a simple text message that describe the operations the plugin has done.

I thought to create a global variable (outside the functions of the plugin) and save the message there.

In the page where i need to show that message I can create and call an hook -> that call a function -> that print the value of this global variable.

What do you think?

Comment: you are looking some like example.php?module=X&action=Y&parameter=Z and save the output where to database??

Comment: @GeoPhoenix yes the URL is similar, then....this plugin does few operations and I need to save the output (simple text message) because I need to write (echo) this message in the page (to see the output of the oeprations that have been done)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bad practice to use global vars =) Why don't you return value of the function? Hook will call this function and print returned value

Answer (score 0):

With a URL such as < example.php?module=X&action=Y&parameter=Z >, something like this should work.

```
<?php
  function actionIsSet(){
    return (isset($_GET["action"]) ? true : false);
  }
  if (actionIsSet()){
    // Do stuff
  }
?>
```

If you need the value of `action`,

```
  function actionIsSet(){
    return (isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : false);
  }
  if (actionIsSet()){
    var action = actionIsSet();
    echo action; // here outputs "Y"
    // Do stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

to get all parameters passed to script

```
$parameters='';
foreach($_GET as $param){
 $parameteters .= $param."\n"; 
}
```

the newline for displaying later , could use nl2br to display in html or write parameters value inside a pre tag

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])){
$output_string .= "variable x was define with value ".$_GET['x'];
}
```

proceed with for checking everything

```
if(){}elseif(){}elseif(){}
```

example ..

```
if(isset($_GET["module"])){
 // checking for module parameters
}elseif(isset($_GET["theme"])){
 // checking for theme parameters
}elseif(isset($_GET["pagebehavior"])){
 // checking for page behavior
}elseif(isset($_GET["cat"])){
 // checking for cat parameters
}
```

it all depends on what parameters you pass and how you structure the ex. module parameters what you want to process and so on..
don't forget to `var_dump($_GET);` to actually see what parameters are passed to the script, and use `echo $string` or store the string to a $_SESSION var or store into database.. making the output available for everyone, i would suggest storing to database and then fetch from the table and process the data